# passing string to a pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-literals, strcpy

I am fairly new in C. I want to assign string in a function to a pointer but I have no idea why it is not working?

This is the initial code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(char* result) {
    *result = "HELLO";
}

int main() {
    char result[64];
    test(result);
    printf("%s", *result);

}
```

This is the error: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. Since * result should store value and result is the address, shouldn't this work out?

Comment: Somewhere near the beginning of your C language book should be a section (likely a whole chapter) on strings, In it, you'll find [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) and its related family of functions mentioned profusely.

Comment: The expression `*result` is exactly equal to `result[0]`. It's the first single character. You need to use `strcpy` to copy the string in the `test` function. And pass plain `result` when calling `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to C.

Your statement:

```
*result = "HELLO";
```

is the same as attempting to do the following:

```
result[0] = "HELLO"
```

which is attempting to set a single character to a string, and you can't do that.

you will need to copy the string character by character

luckily there is a function for that which you have included already with `<string.h>` called `strcpy`

```
strcpy(result,"HELLO")
```

This will work as long as your string to copy is fewer than 63 characters as you have defined in your main() function.

```
char result[64];
```

you should probably also send the length of the string to the test function and use strncpy

```
strncpy(result,"HELLO",length); // safe copy
```

and then terminate the string with '\0'

```
result[length-1] = 0;
```

your printf doesn't need to dereference the string pointer. So simply  `printf("%s",result)`; is fine.

so in summary:

```
void test(char* result,uint32_t len) {
    strncpy(result,"HELLO",len); // safe copy (however "HELLO" will work for 64 length string fine)
    result[len-1] = 0; // terminate the string
}

#define MY_STRING_LENGTH 64

int main() {
    char result[MY_STRING_LENGTH ];
    test(result,MY_STRING_LENGTH);
    printf("%s",result); // remove *

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared an array in main

```
char result[64];
```

Passed to the function it is converted to rvalue of the type char * that points to the first element of the array. The function deals with a copy of this pointer. Changing this copy of the pointer fors not influence on the original array.

Within the function the expression `*result` has the type `char`. So this assignment

```
*result = "HELLO";
```

does not make a sense.

In this call

```
printf("%s", *result);
```

there is again used an incorrect expression of the type char `*result`.

What you need is to use standard string function `strcpy`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(char* result) {
    strcpy( result, "HELLO" );
}

int main( void ) {
    char result[64];
    test(result);
    puts( result );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

When you store a character in a char varible,it puts the ASCII of the character in the memory.

`char c='a';`is the same as`char c=97;`

You can verify this by using the code:

```
char c='a';
printf("%d",c);
```

So here is one way:

```
void test(char* result) {
    *result++ = 'H';
    *result++ = 'E';
    *result++ = 'L';
    *result++ = 'L';
    *result = 'O';
}

int main() {
    char result[64];
    test(result);
    printf("%s", result);
}
```

But it is redundant because there is a function called `strcpy` in `<string.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(char* result) {
    strcpy( resul, "HELLO" );
}

int main() {
    char result[64];
    test(result);
    puts( result );

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the '*' of the variable "result" after you've declared it and use the function "strcpy()" in your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).